# Cancel installation on directory selection in console mode

Tags: install4j

Installer workflow:

1. installer asks you for an installation directory (using directory chooser).
2. if directory exists, display optionDialog with options: continue, retry 
   (retry display directory selection screen again)

This works well in UI. OptionDialog has a Cancel button that you can press then you can press Cancel again to exit installation.

In console mode, I don't seem to be able to cancel gracefully from the optionDialog. I added a third option Quit to the dialog (throwing UserCanceledException) but it doesn't quit installation.

Any thoughts on how I can get an option for the user to Quit installation at this point?

Answer (score 1):

To cancel and to perform a rollback, you can use the "Failure strategy" property of actions. If you call `Util.showOptionDialog` in a "Run script" action, return `false` from the script if the user chooses to cancel and set the "Failure strategy" property of the action to "Quit on failure".